# Navigation Drawer android: use different headerlayout xml when logged in or logged out

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

My navigation drawer works perfect but I want to use a different header layout when I'm logged in or when I'm logged out. I have the below in my MainActivity.

```
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/draw_menu" />
```

Now I  want to use a different app:headerLayout= when logged in (@layout/nav_header_login). How can I do this programmatically?  I looked and looked but cannot find the answer? All help is really appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Have all contents inside nav_header and then hide/show views depending on user is logged in or not.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. If I do this the spaces are still visible and the header will not look nice anymore. Is there no other way?

Comment: There might be other ways and I believe logged in user and logged out view in the navigation drawer should not be much different from a design perspective. But spaces should not be visible. You should set the visibility to GONE or VISIBLE. You can post the layout I might be able to help you out with the spaces.